# Create reports from bunch of strings in java

Tags: java, string, report, reporting

In my project I am using a lot of strings to create reports. Is there any library or API that can create stylish reports (in PDF) in Java? I tried with Jasper reports but it can only create reports from mySQL database.Regards.

Comment: also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText (not free for commercial use) will let you do PDF programmatically (code your layout).  [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) (free) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) (free trials but not free) can do PDF and other formats and work from templates (DOC or ODT) mail-merge style.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Each of the technologies will let you create stylish reports, but working from templates is often faster than working in code if you are starting from scratch.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has several
http://pdfbox.apache.org/

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Or you can use http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try [iText](http://itextpdf.com/download.php). I used it in some of my projects, and it works like a charm.